# dynamic IN clause in SQL statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a SQL statement as shown below. In that i wanted to have IN clause values like `'X','Y','Z'` and this value may vary based on different conditions. But when i give this value at run time SQL statement not giving me any output.

```
SELECT test,test1,test2
FROM test_n 
WHERE NVL(code,'X') in(:code);
```

here

```
:code = 'X','Y','Z'
```

Can any one help me?

Also i cannot use anonymous block or functions to achieve this.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL statement, or you need to pass the list from your application in a loop as separate variables into the `IN` clause

Comment: Can you mention what values you are getting from "code" column of table test_n?

Comment: i may have any one value from NULL or Y or Z

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DEFINE`  by quoting the string ( **substitution** variables)

```
SET DEFINE ':'
DEFINE code  = "'X','Y','Z'"

SELECT test,test1,test2
FROM test_n 
WHERE NVL(code,'X') in(:code);
```

If you want to use true **bind** variables, you could try something like this with a `LIKE` statement.

```
set define off
VARIABLE code VARCHAR2
EXEC :code := 'X,Y,Z'
select test,test1,test2
from   test_n
where  ',' || :code || ',' like '%,' || code || ',%'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like :

`with tab as ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('X,Y,Z', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) code
               FROM DUAL
              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('X,Y,Z','[^,]+',1,LEVEL)  IS NOT NULL)
    select test,test1,test2
    from test_n 
    where nvl(code,'X') in (select code from tab)`